# Default arguments in __init__ of class inheriting from int

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, immutability

I feel like I'm losing my mind. I was working on a simple project involving a subclass of `int`, which may not be the best idea, but I need to inherit many of `int`'s magic methods for integer operations.

I added a default argument `wraps=True` to the class' `__init__` method but started getting an unexpected `TypeError`, where my default argument was being assumed as a keyword argument for `int`.

The section of the code could be simplified to this:

```py
class MyClass(int):

    def __init__(self, a, *args, b=False, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

and for some reason `b` (or in my case, `wraps`) was being passed as a keyword argument to `int`, which of course, didn't work.

After some testing I found that the same problem occurred with `str` but not with most other classes, which means that, (I'm guessing) the problem arises from inheriting from an immutable class. Am I correct and is there a way around this problem?

Thanks in advance.